# Angular make a get passing array

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to make an api call passing an array of id

in my page.ts:

```
this.myService.getPassingID(['1', '2'])
 .subscribe((val) => console.log("val", val))
```

in my service:

```
getPassingID(id): Observable<any>{
let params = new HttpParams()
      .set("id", id)
let url = apiURL 
return this.http.get(url, {params});
}
```

I have tried in this way but I receive 500 error. How can I pass array in api call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it in two ways.

#1 Stringify the array while passing it into params and then send it to the HTTP call

```
let params = new HttpParams().set("id", JSON.stringify(id));
```

This needs you to parse the respective param at your receiving API backend.

```
JSON.parse(params.id)
```

and use it further.

#2 Append all the elements of the array as comma(,) separated values into the `id` param.

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('id', id.join(','));
```

This can be accessed and split on comma(,) at the backend.

```
let idArray = params.id.split(',');
```

and use it further.